# I want to verify my transaction actually arrived

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, transaction-hash

I am new to Monero and just attempted my first transfer from Kraken to my Monero wallet on Aug 23. On the Kraken side, it states the withdrawal was a success. However, on the Monero side I have 0 XMR in my account. It's been seven days. The Daemon and wallet are synchronized (as shown in lower left side of window). However, the height is showing 2149577, and never changes.

Here is a status from log:
[8/27/2023 7:25 PM] 2023-08-27 23:25:43.105 I Monero 'Fluorine Fermi' (v0.18.2.2-release)
Height: 2149577/2149577 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 1.31 GH/s, v12, 0(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 9h 3m 40s

To verify transaction actually arrived the tool is requesting: secret view key, public view key, and transaction ID/hash. I have first two, but not sure how to get transaction ID/hash.